# How are interfaces implemented behind the scenes in the Go language?

Tags: interfaces, polymorphism, go, implementations, golang

I have read [this article](https://golangbyexample.com/inner-working-interface-golang/) which indicates a double tuple structure, but it is unfortunately light on implementation details, which is what I am looking for.

So... how *are* interfaces implemented in Go?

Pure guesswork on my part:

- It cannot be a v-table in the C++ sense, because the interface is implicit - a struct doesn't know it conforms to an interface when compiled, only when passed to a function taking an interface does this actually happen.
- I don't *think* it can be static polymorphism - every function that takes an interface parameter would have to be compile-time aware of every type that might be passed to it and I don't think that's true either.

What else is left?

Comment: I had the same question as you and wrote down my findings here: https://lukasatkinson.de/2018/interface-dispatch/#fat-pointers (but might be partially outdated by now). Yes there's a vtable, but its tracked *outside* of the object, and it may be created lazily by the language runtime.

Comment: Interesting! I assume that in turn this (edit: the fat pointer you write about) implies that a function using interfaces always does pass-by-reference? (Not that this would be a loss compared to any other language I know but that wasn't what I thought was going on in go)

Comment: Based on what I found with a quick search, Go passes references by value similar to how it works in Java and Python.

Comment: @amon lmao check this off topic question lock. Clearly I must have been "asking for assistance in explaining, writing or debugging code, or using coding tools," and any day now I'm sure somebody will be able to helpfully explain which one of those they mistakenly thought I was doing.

Comment: I think it's a good question and on-topic.  I have voted to reopen.  You might want to edit the question to be less conversational and perhaps inline relevant details of the article.  Often the targets of links can vanish so it's best to put the essential details into the text of the question.

Comment: The problem really is that the article explains barely anything, which is why I decided to ask :D But there's probably space for putting the actual question into the body of the text.

Comment: Sometimes it seems like every single question is off topic for here. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I'm really interested in this question.  I have zero experience with Go (the language) and very little knowledge about it but the question you are asking seems really relevant to my interests.  If I edit your question, would that be a problem for you?

Comment: Go ahead - though you may also want to look at [this article](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) that I got when I asked the same question in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/130pkav/how_are_interfaces_implemented_under_the_hood/).

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, there are (kind of) objects that represent interfaces. Say an interface has three functions. Then the interface object has three function pointers and a bit of storage. When you pass an object to a function expecting an interface, an interface object is created, three function pointers are stored, and the data is stored. I think (from memory) that for class instances a reference is stored, for small structs the contents of the struct, and for large structs a pointer is allocated.

Sounds a reasonable way to do this, so Go might do the same. You can convert such an object back to the original type if you know the type. A function using the interface object needs no knowledge of the actual type. Called an “existential interface”, so an interface that actually exists as an object.

Comment: Would you mind if I edit in the precise terms for these? In Swift, these are called _existential containers_. They're 4 words in size: a pointer to the type metadata (called a _protocol witness table_, which has the function pointers, among other things) and 3 words of storage for the value. Small enough values are allocated inline, otherwise the first word is just a pointer to heap-allocated storage. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68024022/3141234 for more detail